# saving a structure of a list with the data in a text file using Python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of tuples which I want to save in a text file as a string and later read it from another Python script and use ast.literal_eval to transform it from string to list.

My question is if its possible to write in a text file not only the data in the list but the whole structure my list of lists of tuples has.

For example to have a text file like this:

```
[[(365325.342877, 4385460.998374), (365193.884409, 4385307.899807), (365433.717878, 4385148.9983749995)]]
```

Does this makes sense?

Comment: Do you *need* the file to be human-readable? Why not use `pickle`? Or, if human readability is important, consider JSON - you get lists rather than tuples, but otherwise the structure is retained. You *can* do what you're thinking of, but it's not the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to keep exactly the same structure cause I am going to use this list later in a python script which expects a list of list of tuples. The file wont be human-readable.

Comment: In that case, use `pickle`. And if the data is huge you can always zip the pickle file. FWIW, Python code that processes a list of lists of tuples _should_ work correctly on a a list of lists of lists, unless you need the immutability of those tuples, eg they need to be hashable so they can be used as dict keys or set elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a situation better suited to `pickle` than writing to a text file and using `ast.literal_eval`.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> l = [(1,2),(3,4)]
>>> with open('new_pickle.txt', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(l, f)

>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('new_pickle.txt' ,'rb') as f:
    l = pickle.load(f)

>>> l
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Writing out the repr will work, so long as all the values are Python built-ins with literal representations (e.g. int, float, str, bytes). But you shouldn't do this; it's limited to Python literals and slower. Use the [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), the Python standard for serializing arbitrary data; it's faster, works with types that lack a literal representation, and (often) produces smaller output (particularly if you're using protocols 2 and higher).

**Edit**: To your concern over reproducibility: pickles reproduce the original structure precisely.